# v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor and v8::Template::Set - Difference

Tags: c++, v8

I'm confused by the difference between V8 ObjectTemplate's Set and SetAccessor methods. My question has a simple **context** and **4 concrete sub-questions**.

#### Context

Let's say I have code snippet that wants to provide a global object `global` to the targeting JS context. `global` has a property `x`, whose value takes int value. `global` also has a property `log`, which is a function. All the snippets are taken from V8's source, [process.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/process.cc#L181) and [Embedder's Guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder%27s-Guide#accessors) to be precise.

```
HandleScope handle_scope(GetIsolate());    

// Create a template for the global object where we set the
// built-in global functions.
Local<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(GetIsolate());
global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(GetIsolate(), "log", 
          NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(),
          FunctionTemplate::New(GetIsolate(), LogCallback));
```

So this code snippet provides function `log` to the global. Then from the Embedder's Guide to accessors, it says

> An accessor is a C++ callback that calculates and returns a value when an object property is accessed by a JavaScript script. Accessors are configured through an object template, using the SetAccessor method.

The code snippet follows:

```
void XGetter(Local<String> property,
          const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info) {
      info.GetReturnValue().Set(x);
}

void XSetter(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value,
         const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info) {
      x = value->Int32Value();
}

// YGetter/YSetter are so similar they are omitted for brevity

Local<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
global_templ->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "x"), XGetter, XSetter);
global_templ->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "y"), YGetter, YSetter);
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global_templ);
```

As I understand this code snippet, it's providing some integer value `x` to the global as the description goes.

Now,from the source of V8, I see ObjectTemplate doesn't have a Set method, instead, it's inherited from parent class Template. From Template's [source code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L4964), it says:

```
/**
 * Adds a property to each instance created by this template.
 *
 * The property must be defined either as a primitive value, or a template.
 */
 void Set(Local<Name> name, Local<Data> value,
         propertyAttribute attributes = None);
```

#### Questions

1. Template's Set method says it can set a primitive value to the instance of the template, then ***can I use Set to set `x` in the second code snippet instead of using SetAccessor?***
2. If the answer to question 1 is true, then what's the difference for setting `x` between using `SetMethod` and `Set`? Is the difference being that any modification in JS to the property set by `Set` will not be reflected in C++?
3. If the answer to question 1 is false, then why can't I use Set on `X`?
4. From the description of accessors, it says it computes and return ***value***. So does it mean we don't use `SetAccessor` to return functions? I'm confused because I mainly write JS and Haskell. Both languages spoils me to take functions as values.

Now I know it should be easy to verify all my assumptions by actually building the samples, but I have difficulties compiling the V8 source, hence I'm asking for any help.

Thank you in advanced for any effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Yes.

**2.** `Set` is the C++ equivalent (modulo property attributes) of:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, "x", {value: 3})
```

`SetAccessor` is the C++ equivalent of:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, "x", {get: function XGetter() { return ...; }, 
                                    set: function XSetter(val) { ... }});
```

As you suggest, a consequence is that in case of `Set`, the C++ side has no way of knowing whether the value was changed from the JavaScript side.

**3.** n/a

**4.** The getter can return any value you want; in particular the value can be a function.